# Combining functions to produce a desired integer output

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math

I'm not sure if this question belongs on stackoverflow or math, but I'll give stackoverflow a shot.

I'm attempting to create an algorithm / function that will allow me to solve a puzzle, but I am simply unable to. The puzzle is as stated.

1. Let a unit be a function that accepts a integer `i` between 0 and 15.
2. A unit can add or subtract any number in the range 0 - 15 to/from i.
3. Additionally, instead of adding or subtracting a number to/from i, a unit can also contain a number from 0-15 and subtract i from that.
4. A unit can only perform 2 operations on a number, and the operation producing the largest value will be the output of the unit.
5. Values only go from 0 - 15, so 9 - 15 = 0 and 13 + 5 = 15.
6. We may combine units together to produce a more complex result.
   The first unit may only accept numbers ranging from 0 - 9.
7. In my examples I will string together 3 units.

This is a problem that is unrelated to coding, but it seems that I need a program to figure out possible solutions. I've attempted to create a brute force algorithm to find solutions, but I've been unable to do so, as I'm not that great with coding.

For example, a problem could be:

For values 1 and 4, let the output be 0. For all others, e.g. 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, the output must be greater than 0.

A solution here might be:

```py
def unit1(input):
    return max(5 - input, input)

def unit2(input):
    max(14 - input, input)

def unit3(input):
    max(10 - input, input - 10)

print(unit3(unit2(unit1(4))))
```

Another example might be:

For values 4, 5, 6 and 8 the output must be 3 or greater. For all others, e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, the output must be less than 3.

A solution here might be:

```py
def unit1(input):
    return max(4 - input, input - 4)

def unit2(input):
    max(2, input)

def unit3(input):
    max(1 - input, input - 6)

print(unit3(unit2(unit1(5))))
```

Given an example as the two stated above, is there a general algorithm / formula I can use to find my desired output?

Additionally, is it possible to solve the problems above using only 2 units?

Please do let me know if I need to elaborate on something, and know that your help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: You aren't truncating to 8 bits anywhere

Comment: Knowing the input and output values, and guessing the function parameters seems like machine learning.

Comment: @MadPhysicist why would i?

Comment: @serv-inc perhaps, although the brute force seems simpler, and I feel like there is a better way to go about it. I just cannot figure it out myself, hence my post.

Comment: So you ask about an algorithm that only solves your specific problem as stated above? Maybe cs.stackexchange might help: they allow questions about ["algorithms, models of computation"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @serv-inc not sure what you mean by _only solves your specific problem as stated above?_. Should find a combination of 3 units for any desired output, not just my examples. That being said, I will indeed make another post on cs. Ty!

Comment: @Cortex. Because of rule #5

Comment: In these examples it does not matter, as the greatest value will always be sellected.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be basically two kinds of things you have to do:  map inputs that should be handled the same way to contiguous ranges, and then move contiguous ranges to the right place.

`max(A-x,x-B)` is the only kind of unit that can map non-contiguous ranges together.  It has limitations:  It always maps 2 inputs onto one output, and you've gotta be careful never to map two inputs that have to be handled differently onto the same output.

In terms of what gets mapped together, you only need one parameter, since `max(x,A-x)` handles all cases.  You can try all 16 possibilities to see if any of them help.   Sometimes you may need to do a saturating add before the max to collapse inputs at the top or bottom of the range.

In your first example, you need to map 0 and 4 together.

In *max(x,A-x)*, we need *4 = A-1*.

Solving that we get *A=5*, so we start with

```
max(x, 5-x)
```

That maps 4 and 1 to 4, and everything else to other values.

Now we need to combine the ranges above and below 4.  Everything less than 4 has to map to something higher than 4.  We solve *5 = A-3* to get *A = 8*:

```
max(x, 8-x)
```

Now the ranges of things that need to be handled the same way are contiguous, so we just need to move them to the right place.  We have values >=4 and we need 4->0.  We could add a subtraction unit, but it's shorter just to shift the previous `max` by subtracting 4 from both cases.  We're left with a final solution

```
max(x, 5-x)
max(x-4, 4-x)
```

You haven't really defined all the possible questions you might be asked, but it looks like they can all be solved by this two step combine-and-shift process.  Sometimes there will be no solution because you can't combine ranges in any valid way with `max`.

Comment: Hey Matt! Ty for taking the time. This method is excellent when I only need to map 2 inputs together, but I dont know how to do it when I have to map more than 2 inputs together. How can I map both 0, 1 and 7 together, is there any way to do this with just one unit?

Comment: Edit: Just realised that is not possible, the worst possible scenario that I need to solve is to map 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 and 9 together. Im unable to tackle this. Would you be willing to update your question with an approach to solving the riddle when you need to map more than 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing piece you need to proceed is a higher-order function. That's a function that returns another function. Something like:

```
def createUnit(sub, add):
    def unit(input):
        return max(sub - input, input + add)
    return unit
```

You can use it like:

```
unit1 = createUnit(5, 0)
unit2 = createUnit(14, 0)
unit3 = createUnit(10, -10)
```

Your first example can be solved with two units, but your second example can't.

I think the key to solving this efficiently is to work backwards from the output to the input, but I haven't spent enough time on it to figure out precisely how to do so.